# React: How to debug why browser showing different value than HTML element in Chrome > Dev Tools?

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I am building an app in react.

**Problem**

My app in Chrome browser is showing a different value than the corresponding HTML element in Dev Tools. This only occurs after a user action on the UI to sort the table. It seems the browser is still showing the old value for that row in the table.

1. Browser showing value = 3 <-- incorrect
2. HTML element has value = 41 <-- correct

See image below:

[image]

**Question**

What steps should I take to diagnose what may be causing this issue?

e.g. is there somewhere I should add specific logs? or is this a known issue in react when someone is doing something clearly wrong?

*Note: This request is more about the how to diagnose such an issue, rather than finding what is specifically wrong with my code.*

Comment: The `value` **attribute** is just a default value of the input per DOM/HTML specification. When the actual value changes due to user input or whatever, the attribute doesn't need to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem **was** in the code it seems. I found the cause through trial and error changing the code.

**Previously**, the render for my component looked like:

```
 render() {
    return (
      <td className="hoverWrapper">
          <input
            className="wrappedContent"
            type="number"
            onBlur={this.inputChangeHandler}
            value={this.props.value}
          ></input>
          <EditOnhoverbutton />
      </td>
    )
  }
```

**Changed to:**

```
 render() {
    const showValue = this.props.value ? this.props.value : "";
    return (
      <td className="hoverWrapper">
          <input
            className="wrappedContent"
            type="number"
            onBlur={this.inputChangeHandler}
            value={showValue}
          ></input>
          <EditOnhoverbutton />
      </td>
    )
  }
```

I suspect the underlying cause was related to the fact that for some rows `this.props.value` did not exist, and trying to render `undefined` caused the render to fail, and the original value continued to display.

If anyone can provide a better assessment, I would be grateful.